# Closed circuit with LM324n opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTY33E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

I am using an LM324n opamp with dual supply in the circuit as shown with ADC and DAC ports of an Arduino Due board.

I am getting the expected voltage output range of 0V to 3V at the ADC which I give to DAC. Since the DAC voltage range is different from ADC, I used the amplifier circuit in the dotted box as a rectifier to get 0V to 3V output range which is then given to another amplifier circuit whose output is connected to the input as feedback.

Since I am not using any external current source I am expecting 0V when connected as a closed circuit but unfortunately I am getting 1.62V to -1.64V  for the input range as shown (1.65V to -1.65V at non inverting terminal).

Is there any reason for this, and can anyone suggest how to rectify this if there is any way? Is my assumtion of 0v output for closed circuit  correct?

Comment: It appears that English is not your first language. (You should say this in your user profile so we can help you out.) You need to write sentences with a '.' between each one and start the next with a capital letter. I see that JRE has done this for you as I write.

Comment: @BrianDrummond -- not the OPs fault -- I guess it's a CircuitLab export issue.  It opens fine in circuitlab.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Agreed, the Circuitlab version is a good addition.

Comment: @BrianDrummond sorry for the inconvenience i hope the circuit is visible now

Comment: hey guys i am still struggling with this concept. i tried to change the gain of the 3rd op amp circuit to see if anything varies but no use.would be a great help to know if there is any mistake in the circuit and my assumption asked in the question above.